# Android, In-App billing implementation, correct way of implementation

Tags: android

I am implementing an In-App billing feature in our Android App.

App is a free app, with few features but for one feature user has to pay.
Goal is to make one of the feature available only for the people who purchase it via In-App billing.

is it correct way to ship all the feature as part of the free app and hide the paid feature and make this feature available (unhide) only for the paid users?
Or
When user pays via In-App billing should i have to download new version/required files to make this feature available? if this is the correct way, how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you ship all functioning code, but you check if the item has been paid before you let the user use it: [API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html).

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: I was just wandering if there is anyway to hack and make this feature available without paying..
it is an Apache Cordova hybrid app with UI implementation in HTML5, Javascript, CSS3 and Business logic in Java..

Comment: Hack is always possible. But the logic I exposed is Google's official implementation guide and is the way to go.